# assert_select empty data attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I wish to write a view test to assert the presence of an *empty* data attribute within my HTML.

My HTML is like this:

`<section data-my-name-here></section>`

My test is:

`assert_select '[data-my-name-here]'`

The test result is:

`Expected at least 1 element matching "[data-my-name-here'']", found 0.`

*note how the test adds quotes to the attribute where it seems to expect a value.*

I can make the test pass if I add a value in my HTML and test for that e.g.

`<section data-my-name-here='true'></section>`

`assert_select "[data-my-name-here='true']"`

but I don't want to change my markup for the sake of the test.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resorting to using Nokogiri, seems to me that `assert_select` does not recognise attributes without a value, at least I did not change the view.

`html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse self.rendered
my_element_count = html.xpath('//*[@data-my-name-here]').size
assert_equal 1, my_element_count`